# Is there any transfer function packages available for Open Modelica?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I'm a research trainee building a model of powerplant in Open Modelica and the governing equations contain transfer fuctions in laplace transform. Can someone send a link to the laplace transform packages for open modelica ? Google dint help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transfer functions can be simulated with `Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.TransferFunction` which is part of the *Modelica Standard Library*.

Regards 
Rene Just Nielsen

Comment: Thank You, if you know any active forums for Open Modelica, please let me know.

Comment: You're welcome. I think Stack Exchange is a good (active) forum for Modelica-related discussions and I know that some of the OpenModelica developers are active here too. There is an OpenModelica specific forum on https://openmodelica.org/forum.